# Python C API : Convert PyObject pointer to C data type

Tags: python, python-c-api

I need to convert a `PyObject*` to and `int` variable in C.
I understand we can parse arguments with `PyArg_ParseTuple` and that we can build Python object using `Py_BuildValue` but what is the 'inverse' of `Py_BuildValue`?

For instance say I have a Python tuple `(1, 2)` and I'd like to use the content of the tuple to access an array :

```
int x, y;
PyObject* t_0, t_1;

t_0 = PyTuple_GetItem(tuple_ref, 0);
t_1 = PyTuple_GetItem(tuple_ref, 1);
//t_0 and t_1 are of type PyObject* and I need to use them to access a C array 
//convert t_0 and t_1 to int and save them in x and y, how?
```

Comment: What's wrong with `PyArg_ParseTuple`? I know it's mostly used on function arguments but it doesn't have to be

Comment: @DavidW Ah, I really tought I was exclusive for argument parsing. I've figured out there is a ```PyLong_AsLong(PyObject* val)``` function allowing the conversion. If you'd like to write both this comment and yours as an answer I'll gladly accept it and close the question!